# Why can't I set "style" directly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's suppose I have a `<div>`. I set its `style` to `color:red`.

```
<div style="color:red">text</div>
```

Why can't I set `style` through javascript like so:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style="color:blue";
```

But only can set property of style:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.color="blue";
```

Comment: Because the `.style` that you reference is actually a structure that contains a bunch of different properties. `.color` being one of them. Something you _could_ use in this manner however is `document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].setAttribute('style', 'color:blue');` - This will give you markup that resembles your first code-block. (which then gets parsed by the browser, setting the `.style.color` attribute of the element to 'blue')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dom model. What js debug tool do you use? Run this in your browser console:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style
```

This will be result:

[image]

So, this command returned object. By this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style="color:blue";
```

You redefining object. It is not correct at all.

That's it and you can't do anything with it.

If you want to have a tool to manage css properties better you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/): [`prop()` function](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.cssText = "color: blue;"
```

src: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_csstext.asp

Comment: My bad ^_^. Use the cssText property.